# Div with canvas and image responsive

Tags: jquery, html, responsive-design

Wha I am trying to do seems easy, but being consuming my energy a loooot.
I have this [example here](http://jsfiddle.net/franciscocarvalho/7v8y5/12/) that simply shows me a Div and Canvas when I hover an img.
The question is, how can I make this three things responsive?

Heres's my *HTML*, with style inside

```
<div class="map maphilighted" style="display: block; background: url("
logocultura.png
") repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent; position: relative; padding: 0px; width: 720px; height: 305px;">
    <canvas style="width: 720px; height: 305px; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px none; opacity: 1;"
    height="305" width="720"></canvas>
    <img class="map maphilighted" width="720" height="305" usemap="#usa"
    src="logocultura.png" style="opacity: 0; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px none;"></img>
</div>
```

Comment: Rule one for responsive design would be to avoid using pixels and use percentage values..

Comment: @prasannaAarthi Yep, and I tryed to change ALL px to %, with calculations to avoid differences. I guess that this issue comes cause this canvas (made by % map) doesn't force the %.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make it responsive, you should change the width property to a proportion.
Try this:

```
<div class="map maphilighted" style="display: block; background: url("http://www.gloper.org/highplay.pt/images/cultura/logocultura.png") repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent; position: relative; padding: 0px; width: 100%; height: auto;">
<canvas style="width: 100%; height: auto; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px none; opacity: 1;" height="305" width="720"></canvas>
<img class="map maphilighted" width="720" height="305" usemap="#usa" src="/highplay.pt/images/cultura/logocultura.png" style="opacity: 0; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px none;"></img>
</div>
```

Comment: doesn't work. What I am trying to make responsive is this [link](http://www.gloper.org/highplay.pt/quem-somos/cultura), that fits nicely in 1920 wide screen but its too large in small screens.

Comment: Then use media-query. If you want the image to displayed smaller for 400px or less, do this in your css file: @media (width-max: 400px) { .maphilighted { width: 50%; } }